# subprocess output data word recognition

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

may be this question was asked already but i cant find answer what works for me so please need your help . I try write script what automaticly will start another script if service down, in my case apache2 , i write small script but i cant make it work its not recognize output , please your help , here the script :

```
    import os
    import subprocess
    service = "apache2"
    p = subprocess.Popen(["systemctl", "is-active", service], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    output = output.decode('utf-8')
    print 'APA Serv :',(output)
    if output == "inactive":
        print '\x1b[31;1m' + ' Attention!' + '\x1b[0m'
        os.system('sudo python baz.py')
        time.sleep(2)
    p.stdout.close()
```

Comment: `output` probably ends with a newline. Use `output.decode('utf-8').strip()`

Comment: So SImple !!!! Brother you my Hero !!! It works for me , Thanks a lot !